# Blank area at the bottom of a combobox when scroll bar is visible

Tags: wpf, combobox, scrollbar

I've noticed that when a WPF combobox has enough items to cause the vertical scroll bar to appears (seems to be 18), a blank area also appears for a horizontal scroll bar.

[image: combobox with blank space]

I guess the horizontal scroll bar is hidden instead of collapsed. Is there any way to make it either collapsed or visible?

I thought this might be some obscure style in our code, or something wrong with the way we loaded items from the database, or the binding, but it still appears in a new test project:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfComboScrollbar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfComboScrollbar"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="150">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <ComboBox >
                <ComboBoxItem >Item1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item3</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item4</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item5</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item6</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item7</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item8</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item9</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item10</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item11</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item12</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item13</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item14</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item15</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item16</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item17</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem >Item18</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: As far as i know a `ScrollbarVisibility` can't be set to collapsed, only `Auto`, `Disabled`, `Hidden` or `Visible`. You may want to try what fits best by adding `<ComboBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="VISIBILITY">` to your xaml.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all four options but the first three all leave a blank space. `Visible` at least displays a disabled scroll bar in that space, which is better than the users thinking there's a blank item at the end of the list, but still not great. Is this an issue that everyone just lives with?

Comment: Thanks @pjrki, setting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" does solve the problem! Any idea why it works?

Comment: No problem @RobinBennett . Setting up ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to False disables virtualization, which basically means that whole space that is needed for the combobox popup is calculated just before getting into view. This means that it will disable virtualization which is by default turned on. IMO when the virtualization is turned on, scrollviewer is in item-by-item scrolling mode and that's why there's extra space because of VirtualizingStackPanel calculations. When you turn it off then ScrollViewer is in pixel-by-pixel mode.